# Raspberry pi shutdown button with a delay

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I have a raspberry Pi that i had added an shutdown button on the GPIO using this script:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import os

gpio_pin_number=21
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(gpio_pin_number, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

try:
    GPIO.wait_for_edge(gpio_pin_number, GPIO.FALLING)
    os.system("sudo shutdown -h now")
except:
    pass

GPIO.cleanup()
```

It works like a charm, but more than once i had pressed the button by accident, so to avoid this problem, i want to mod the script so it requires you to hold the button for N seconds instead just pressing it.

So if any one can point me in the right direction (i'm not very good in python) i would be glad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sleep N seconds, read the GPIO value using GPIO.input, if it's still 0 then run your shutdown command. – larsks 1 min ago   edit

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import os
import time

gpio_pin_number=21
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(gpio_pin_number, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

while True:
    GPIO.wait_for_edge(gpio_pin_number, GPIO.FALLING)
    time.sleep(2)
    if GPIO.input(gpio_pin_number) == 0:
        break

os.system("sudo shutdown -h now")
```

The above would require you to hold the button down for two seconds.